# If I attain turiya is it possible to turn things to gold by rubbing one's feces over it?

Tags: tantra, siddhi, samhita

If I attain *turiya* is it possible to turn things to gold by rubbing one's feces over it?
I've read that a yogi can convert iron into gold by rubbing his feces or urine over it.

> *Śivasaṃhitā* and *Khecarīvidyā*, which retain a strong link with tantric traditions teach that yoga may produce more specifically tantric powers such as alchemy and the ability to find buried treasure. These texts appear, however, to be somewhat mischievously trumping tantric practices with yoga: the *Śivasaṃhitā* and the *Dattātreyayogaśāstra* (10.17) say that the yogi may turn iron into gold by smearing it with his urine or faeces, while, in a passage full of terms borrowed from alchemical texts, *Khecarīvidyā* 2.72–9 says that the yogi may perfect his body by rubbing it with his excreta. This is a development of a notion found in Hemacandra’s *Yogaśāstra*, in which the perfected yogi’s excreta and even his touch are said to have supernatural powers (10.15).

Source reference: *Roots of Yoga* by James Mallinson and Mark Singleton, available on [Google Books](https://books.google.nl/books?id=f-UPDQAAQBAJ&pg=PT398&lpg=PT398&dq=feces+turn+into+gold+%22yoga%22&source=bl&ots=7091AStZZV&sig=ACfU3U3zEOOCLq2VWc7C8DW6N_BwoikYbA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiN1N68_bjzAhWEzaQKHYWnAIoQ6AF6BAgiEAM#v=onepage&q=feces%20turn%20into%20gold%20%22yoga%22&f=false).

Comment: You don't need to attain turiya state for such siddhis.

Comment: Those who attain to siddhis do not attain to turiya. See Patanjali's Yoga Sutras.

Comment: This is kinda gross disgusting 